# make statistics of the tag use in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I want to create a list how many times one tag use.
It will make me decide which one to put in `org-tag-persistent-alist`

The data used can be obtained from `org-agenda-files` or a specified file. Is there any emacs function to do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following chunk of elisp to create a dynamic block containing a table where each row is a tag and number of use of that tag in the file.  Add the block to your org file and hit `C-c C-c` to expand it:

```
#+BEGIN: tagblock
#+END:
```

If you only want to count certain tags you can add a `:tags` option to the block and to add a label to the resulting table use `:label`

```
#+BEGIN: tagblock :tags ("tag1" "tag2" "tag3") :label tag-counts
| tag1 | 2 |
| tag2 | 4 |
| tag3 | 8 |
#+END:
```

With the `:todo` option, only entries with a todo state (either any or in a list you specify) will be counted.

All the real work is done by the function `org-freq-count` which takes a parameterized search string (the same as an agenda tags search) and replaces `%s` in the search with each element of `targets`, counting the number of matches.  If `cmp` is given, it will be used as a comparison function when sorting the output.  This code requires the external packages `dash` and `s`, which can be installed from the [MELPA](https://melpa.org/) repository

```
(require 'dash)
(require 's)

(defun org-freq-count (search targets &optional cmp)
  (let ((cmp (if (functionp cmp)
                 cmp
               (lambda (a b) nil))))

    (mapcar (lambda (x)
              (list x (length (org-map-entries t (format search x) nil))))
            (sort
             (delete-dups
              (-filter #'stringp targets))
             cmp)
            )
    ))

(defun org--tagblock-all-tags ()
  (-filter #'stringp (-map #'car (append
                                  (org-get-buffer-tags)
                                  org-tag-alist
                                  org-tag-persistent-alist))))

(defun org-write-freq-count (search targets name)
  (insert (s-concat
           (if name (insert (format "#+NAME: %s\n" name)))
           (mapconcat
            (lambda (x) (format "| %s | %s |" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x)))
            (org-freq-count search targets)
            "\n")))
  (org-table-align)
  )

(defun org-dblock-write:tagblock (params)
  (let ((todo (plist-get params :todo))
        (tags (or (plist-get params :tags) (org--tagblock-all-tags)))
        (label (plist-get params :label))
        (caption (plist-get params :caption))
        )
    (when caption (insert (format "#+CAPTION: %s\n" caption)))
    (org-write-freq-count (cond ((equal todo t)
                                 (format "%%s/%s" (mapconcat 'identity
                                                             org-not-done-keywords
                                                             "|"
                                                             )))
                                ((listp todo)
                                 (format "%%s/%s" (mapconcat 'identity
                                                             todo
                                                        "|"
                                                        )))
                                (t "%s"))
                        tags
                        label
                        )))
```

Comment: Very thoughtful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. One minor point: you probably should mention that the code requires `dash.el` and `s.el`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass the results to R (or some other program) to do the
calculations.

```
#+name: tags
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(let (tags)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (dolist (tag (org-get-tags))
       (push (list tag) tags))))
  tags)
#+end_src

#+begin_src R :var tags=tags
sort(table(tags), decreasing=TRUE)
#+end_src

#+results:
| work     | 3 |
| home     | 2 |
| noexport | 1 |
```